# Sharing controllers and views between areas in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am about to segregate my MVC3 app into areas, but some controllers and views are common to multiple areas. How can I share these?

I have considered some options here, but would rather take some advice first. I can locate shared controllers/views in the core app, i.e. no in any area, and route and or redirect to actions on these controllers. I can also place controllers in a shared library, and use derived controllers in my areas. Then, similar to my first option, I can use custom controller factories in my areas and use these to target shared controllers in the core app.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on *what* is common.

Is the HTML common? Then use editor templates or partials and place them in the Shared folders.

Is the controller code common? Then use child actions with the action itself placed in a controller in the root (e.g not in an area).

It's a matter of preference. I'm a big fan of keeping my controllers DRY, so i like use child actions for rendering of common content (think the RHS modules on this page, they would each be a child action for me).

My colleague on the other hand prefers to use abstractions on the view models and duplicate the data access/setup logic in the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

try this.. I think it will help you. http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib/

Comment: Thanks @Sasha, I will look into that a bit more, but that seems more geared to sharing between applications, requiring the complexity of packaging I feel is bit of overkill for me.